# How to implement jQuery datepicker offline

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Brand new to jQuery and I am having trouble implementing jQuery in an offline setting. I've followed the very helpful posts in Stack Exchange, but still can not get this jQuery datepicker to work.

The date field shows up but it does not pull up the calendar UI. Any direction would be appreciated. Here is the html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dev/css/style.css">
  <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well... i mean... you've still gotta include jquery and jquery ui if you wana use jquery and jquery ui. being offline doesn't change that. Why not just use type="date"?

Comment: what errors did you get in the console?

Comment: ReferenceError: $ is not defined @ /dev/cal.aspx:18

Comment: $( function() {

Comment: right, `$` is undefined, as it should be.

Comment: Here you go: Request URL:
    http://10.52.80.6/dev/jquery-1.9.1.min.css
  
  
    Request Method:
    GET
  
  
    Status Code:
    HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Comment: looks like the css file wasn't also downloaded and installed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the file names were not exactly matching and when I verified and fixed this everything worked.